# Weakly connected components in petgraph?

Tags: petgraph

I see an algo for strongly connected components; I see a union-find data structure; but I can't find a weakly connected components function or a straightforward way to compose the provided operations to perform it.

I'm sure I could write it myself but I'd much rather use a standard and well tested library....am I missing it somewhere?

Comment: What's wrong with running a strongly connected components algo ignoring edge direction?

Comment: Nothing would be wrong with that, that’d be great.  Like I said I couldn’t see a way to do that with the api.  I see I’m getting downvoted so I must be doing something wrong, but unfortunately I don’t know what.  Hints on either would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea why you are getting downvoted, but I hear searching for a software library is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks!  By "here" I assume you mean the 'rust' tag -- I have removed that and just kept the 'petgraph' tag, which is the library I'm asking about.  I'm not looking for a library, I'm asking how to accomplish the goal using that specific library, which seems to be the general-purpose standard library for graph algos in rust.